# Did the scene where Rimuru says "I'm not a bad slime" used to have "slurp" at the end?

Tags: reincarnated-as-a-slime, censorship

I can't find anyone else who remembers it, but I'm sure that in the original Japanese version of *That Time I Was Reincarnated as a Slime*, Rimuru's line "I'm not a bad slime" was followed by "slurp".

I watched it a few times before it got removed. It was removed from the sub after the dub came out and didn't have it. Maybe there are not any sub viewers in the groups I have talked to, but still.

Did this scene actually exist as I remember it?

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga Stack Exchange. To help potential answerers, could you mention the episode and possibly the timestamp?

Comment: That Time I Got Reincarnated as a Slime
Episode 6
Timestamp of 14:04 - 14:07
Well on the cruncyroll sub at least, but it should get you around the area